Problem with rasterize vector layer to raster
I am trying to rasterize a vector layer by the rasterized tool for an university project (QGIS version 3.36.1). My lecturer did it without entering a burn-in value (because it is optional) and just set the output raster size unit to georeferenced units with a horizontal and vertical resoultion of 30 m each. I tried to do the same but needed to enter a burn-in value otherwise the result was like seen below.
Does someone know a way of doing it without the burn-in value to get a result? I need the raster data to continue using focal statistics on it.


